# Not able to see "Invoke ANT" option on Jenkins 2.85

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am using Jenkins version 2.85 and trying to invoke or add ANT plugin. However, I can't see "Invoke ANT" option under Global Tool Configuration.

I have configured ANT and verified the version as follows.
**Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed**

Kindly let me know how can I get "Invoke ANT" option.

Thanks,
Narasimha

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install [Jenkins ANT plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin) for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Ant Plugin** by going to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available Tab and search for Ant and install all the relevant ant plugin.

Configure ant plugin by going to Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration.

You'll see an option **Ant**, either install Ant if you don't have on the local system or if you have ant configured on your local system, directly provide the ANT_HOME.